# Clustered index in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a composite primary key. It creates clustered index. If I use a few columns from that composite primary key in a `WHERE` clause, will that index be still effective? Or do I have to make new index based on the columns used in `WHERE`? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any index, whether clustered or not, is only useful to a query provided it's Left-most columns in the definition are all part of the WHERE clause.

If you have an index on `(Col1,Col2,Col3)`, then this index can be useful for WHERE clauses that use all 3 columns, or `Col2` and `Col1`, or just `Col1`. But as soon as `Col1` *isn't* included in the search, the index is useless.

Comment: It may be useful for a col1, col3 search but YMMV. And I'd like to add then the WHERE clause order won't matter, so col1, col2 is the same as col2, col1 *only* in the WHERE clause though... +1 too

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers. Great help. BTW, what is YMMV?

Comment: @gmail user - Your Mileage May Vary - a way of indicating that the advice being provided may or may not be correct in your particular situation/environment, so you'd be well advised to test it with your real data/queries before relying on it as being true.

Comment: Excellent. Learn something new

Answer (score 1):

If ever possible, I try to avoid composite keys - especially the primary key. Also: if you have a composite key, it's only effective if you use the left-most n columns, e.g. if you have a column at the third position in your composite key and your search only has a `WHERE` on that third column, the index won't be able to be used.

The clustering key would ideally be a small, stable, unique and ever-increasing column  - INT or BIGINT as your default option. Don't overload your clustering key! Don't make it too wide, and by all means, try to avoid columns of varying size (like `VARCHAR` - they carry additional overhead)

There's another issue to consider: the clustering key on a table will be added to each and every entry on each and every non-clustered index on your table as well - thus you really want to make sure it's as small as possible. Typically, an INT with 2+ billion rows should be sufficient for the vast majority of tables - and compared to a GUID as the clustering key, you can save yourself hundreds of megabytes of storage on disk and in server memory.

Some more food for thought - excellent stuff by Kimberly Tripp - read it, read it again, digest it! It's the SQL Server indexing gospel, really.

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEY and/or clustered key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)